# Я не знаю как дальше делать

Tags: python

Дана строка, состоящая из чисел, которые являются элементами списка.  Нумерация элементов начинается с 0. Напишите программу, которая выведет элементы списка, номера которых четны (0, 2, 4...).

Sample Input:

1 2 3 4 5 6
Sample Output:

```
s = [input()]
d = []
x = 0

While x < len(s):
if s[x] % 2 == 0:
    d.append(s[x])
x + 1
```

1 3 5

Comment: что является номером? не x-ли? тогда `if s[x] %2 == 0` заменяется на `if x %2  == 0`

Answer (score 0):

```
s = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
for i in range(0, len(s), 2):
    print(s[i])
```

Вывод:

```
1
3
5
```

Или

```
b = []
s = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
for i in range(0, len(s), 2):
    b.append(s[i])
print(*b)
```

Вывод:

```
1 3 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Отступы важны,
объявляй переменные которые планируешь использовать,
если нужны нечетные символы - условие != 0,
while с маленькой буквы

```
s = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
d = []
x = 0
while x < len(s):
    if s[x] % 2 != 0:
        d.append(s[x])
    x += 1
print(d)
```

я бы сократил вот так

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
print([i for i in x if i % 2 != 0])
```

Answer (score 0):

самый короткий вариант - например с помощью срезов

```
s = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

d = s[::2] # пройтись с начала до конца списка s и выбрать каждый 2 элемент

print(*d)
```